# React router starts showing page content only when transition is complete

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, react-navigation

I use React router in my Ionic 5 project and it's working fine, unless the page transitions.

Pages are blank as long as the transition is not completed. This happens in Chrome on my Macbook as well as in Safari on my iPhone.

**Screen recording video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bHyf6i_j92CcGPQzEYjM4CmEAdeXhrNJ/view?usp=sharing

How to solve that? Thanks in Advance!